# Mass gpupdate /force with power shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, gpo

This is what I am doing:

```
$cn = Get-ADComputer -filt *
$cred = Get-Credential domain\user
$session = New-PSSession -cn $cn.name -cred $cred
icm -Session $session -ScriptBlock {gpupdate /force}
```

The issues is I don't really need to update all PC's. I have a pool of 90 VMs all with the name example-1 to example-90. How would I target only those with example in the name?

Answer (score 1):

```
$cn = Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like 'example*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work. To use the filter parameter on `Get-ADComputer` you need `{}` unless you are using `-filter *` in which case you don't.

Also the AD property is not name, but DistinguishedName

This should work...

```
$cn = Get-ADComputer -Filter {DistinguishedName -like 'example*'}
```

Also you will need to enumerate the returned machines as there will be more than one object returned. This is what your solution should look like:

```
$cn = Get-ADComputer -Filter {DistinguishedName -like 'example*'}
$cred = Get-Credential domain\user

ForEach ($item in $cn) {
  $session = New-PSSession -cn $item.name -cred $cred
  Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    gpupdate /force
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but my IT Director will not add the exception to the firewall to be able to use the remote functions from PowerShell :/